# How to fix ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error?

Tags: encryption, tls1.2

How to fix the ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error?

In one of our CentOS server, we are encountering the following error in Chrome

`A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an unsupported protocol with Error Code - ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

We tried following command - `openssl s_client -connect <<domain>>:<<port>> -tls1_2`

It gives the following output. It doesn't provide a chain of certificates and negotiated cipher.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect <<domain>>:<<port>> -tls1_2

CONNECTED(00000003)
139874418423624:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1275:SSL alert number 40
139874418423624:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1505770082
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

We checked available ciphers on VM using command - `# /usr/bin/openssl ciphers -v`. This command provides a list of available ciphers which also include ciphers supported by TLS 1.2

We also checked certificates. The same certs work on different servers.

Can someone please guide what is missing in this scenario?

Comment: Rather than openssl can you try with curl and check if it's success

Answer (score 0):

When we use `openssl`, if the connection gets terminated with the `alert 40` error, that means we should explicitly specify the servername in our command, so that the server can return the right certificate the client is expecting.

Specify the exact hostname you want with `-servername` parameter. E.g:

```
openssl s_client -connect yourserver.domain.com:443 -servername  yourserver.domain.com
```